GKE Ingress for Cloud Run
Is there a way how can I please configure Ingress to have both GKE + Cloud Run? Like at this picture from Google Cloud Tech YT video?

Or how they achieve that? Is it from GKE Gateway or Cloud Deploy? Or it must be defined at service level? Does this need some special config on GKE cluster. We are using Autopilot. Thanks for any help.

If you have time to check my answer, I am looking forward to your feedback to understand whether the provided information has helped you in resolving the issue. If not, I am happy to assist further.

It can be doable using url maps as documented here.
You will need to add GKE and Cloud Run as a backend to the same load balancer and there define the path roules for each backend.

To configure Ingress for both Google Kubernetes Engine (GKE) and Cloud Run:
Set Up Your GKE Cluster: Make sure your GKE Autopilot cluster is up and running. You’ll also want to make sure that the required APIs are enabled in your Google Cloud project, such as the Kubernetes Engine API and the Cloud Run API.
Deploy Your Applications: Deploy your applications on GKE and Cloud Run. You’ll typically expose your GKE services through Kubernetes Services, while Cloud Run services can be accessed via their specific endpoints. Follow this below configuration:
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - host: example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /cloud-run-service
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: cloud-run-service
            port:
              number: 80

Service Configuration: For Cloud Run, you will need to create a Cloud Run service that your Ingress . You can use the service URL as the backend for your Ingress rules. Cloud Run services are typically accessed via their URLs, configure the Ingress to use an external service by creating an appropriate backend service.
You need to add GKE and Cloud Run as backends to the load balancer and define routing rules for each backend there.
Refer this Configure Ingress for external Application Load Balancers and Use URL maps  which may helps to resolve your issue

Thanks @Hemanth. Can You please show me, how  to write Cloud Run service? GKE service and url mapping in ingress, works fine, but I cant bind Cloud Run in my ingress. I understand that must be some backend configured in Service, but I even cant use external type of service, since GKE Ingress saying that is not allowed... Thanks for helping.

Hi @Lukáš Prudil Ingress for Cloud Run which may helps to resolve your issue
